# How do I count values in different tables using JOIN and/or UNION in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I want to count the `product_name` in these tables together:

```
jan_product                feb_product
+------------+             +------------+
|product_name|             |product_name|
+------------+             +------------+
|A           |             |A           |
+------------+             +------------+
|A           |             |B           |
+------------+             +------------+
|C           |             |C           |
+------------+             +------------+
```

I want my result to look like:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|product_name|jan_count|feb_count|
+------------+---------+---------+
|A           |2        |1        |
+------------+---------+---------+
|B           |0        |1        |
+------------+---------+---------+
|C           |1        |1        |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

So I tried the query below (I'm using MYSQL so I couldnt try FULL JOIN):

```
SELECT 
    j.product_name, 
    count(j.product_name) as jan_count,
    count(f.product_name) as feb_count
FROM jan_product as j  
JOIN feb_product as f
ON j.product_name = f.product_name
group by j.product_name

UNION

SELECT 
    f.product_name, 
    count(j.product_name) as jan_count,
    count(f.product_name) as feb_count
FROM jan_product as j  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN feb_product as f
ON f.product_name = j.product_name
group by f.product_name
;
```

But i got this instead:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|product_name|jan_count|feb_count|
+------------+---------+---------+
|A           |2        |2        | --- A counts for FEB is wrong
+------------+---------+---------+
|B           |0        |1        |
+------------+---------+---------+
|C           |1        |1        |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

I do not know what to do to get to the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with count from Union all. I would rather advise you to have one table with a month column.

> ```
> create table jan (pname char(1));
> create table feb (pname char(1));
> insert into jan values('A'),('A'),('C');
> insert into feb values ('A'),('B'),('C');
> select
>   pname, 
>   count(j) jan,
>   count(f) feb
> from
>   (select pname,pname j,null f from jan
>     union all
>   select pname,null,pname from feb) jf
> group by pname
> ```
>
> ```
> pname | jan | feb
> :---- | --: | --:
> A     |   2 |   1
> B     |   0 |   1
> C     |   1 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cac3207b350d5b4b16cbdd61d9f67219)*

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the table structure for a minute ... try using a UNION ALL, including an extra column to indicate the source month. Then use a conditional SUM to calculate the totals for each month.

See also [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e4b26284fb7e86a2738a7f403c8ccfa)

```
SELECT  t.product_name
        , SUM( CASE WHEN t.month_number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jan_count
        , SUM( CASE WHEN t.month_number = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS feb_count
FROM   (
           SELECT CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED) AS month_number, product_name
           FROM   jan_product
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT CAST(2 AS UNSIGNED) AS month_number, product_name
           FROM   feb_product
       ) t      
GROUP BY t.product_name
```

**Results:**

```
product_name | jan_count | feb_count
:----------- | --------: | --------:
A            |         2 |         1
C            |         1 |         1
B            |         0 |         1
```

Having said that, you should [normalize](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8ac318edec9c05117ee34abf823e0c9) the model. You could greatly simplify things by storing everything in a single table, with a date (or month + year columns) instead of having a separate table *for each month*.

Also, it seems like you're storing information about *events* that occur to a specific product over time. If that's the case, you should have a separate table containing *unique* products:

| ProductId | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A |
| 2 | Product B |
| 3 | Product C |

Other tables that store information about products should store the "Product" table's unique PK (primary key) value - **not** a product's name. For example, if you had a ProductSales table

```
 | ProductId | SaleDate    | Quantity |
 |-----------|-------------|----------|
 |   1       | 02/01/2022  | 15       |
 |   2       | 02/10/2022  | 4        |
 |   1       | 02/12/2022  | 3        |
 |   3       | 02/01/2022  | 20       |
```

To retrieve information about the sales by month, all you'd need is a simple JOIN between the two tables

See also [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8ac318edec9c05117ee34abf823e0c9)

```
SELECT p.product_name
       , year(s.sales_date) AS sales_year
       , SUM( CASE month(s.sales_date) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jan_sales
       , SUM( CASE month(s.sales_date) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS feb_sales
       , SUM( CASE month(s.sales_date) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mar_sales
       -- ... etc
FROM   product p LEFT JOIN product_sales s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_name
        , year(s.sales_date) 
;
```

**Results:**

```
product_name | sales_year | jan_sales | feb_sales | mar_sales
:----------- | ---------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
Product A    |       2022 |         0 |         2 |         0
Product B    |       2022 |         0 |         1 |         0
Product C    |       2022 |         0 |         1 |         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Please try using below query
-------
WITH cte AS
           ( SELECT * FROM jan_product
             UNION
             SELECT * FROM feb_product)

SELECT cte.product_name,
       j.Jan_count,
       count(f.product_name) as February_count
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_name,
           COUNT(product_name) as Jan_count
           FROM jan_product
           GROUP BY product_name) j
ON cte.product_name=j.product_name
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_name,
           COUNT(product_name) as Feb_count
           FROM feb_product
           GROUP BY product_name) f
ON cte.product_name=f.product_name
```